# How to take more than two words from a textField at different times

Tags: java, swing

I have this code with one textField and  want a user to be able to type through the words in a sentence, like a typing test pressing enter after each word entered. The first word the user typed should be compared to the first word in the sentence, and the second word he types be compared to the second word in the sentence in that order.

The code works fine for the first word typed, but the second time the user types it does not work.

this is the code

```
package actions;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Actions {

   JTextField input;

    public Actions(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setLayout(null);

    input = new JTextField();
    input.setBounds(10, 20, 180, 25);
    f.add(input);

    f.setSize(450,450);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setTitle("Key event Actions");
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //register even handler
    ActionHandler handler = new ActionHandler();
   input.addActionListener(handler); 
    }

    public void recursion(String current){
    }

   private class ActionHandler implements ActionListener{
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           if(e.getSource()==input){
               String userInput = e.getActionCommand();
               String sentence = "samad is going to school";
               String[] words = sentence.split(" ");

           for(int i=0; i<words.length;i++){
                 if (userInput.equals(words[0])) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "They match!");
                     input.setText("");

                     break;
               } 
                 else {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "They don't match!");
                     input.setText("");
                     break;
                 }
              }
           }
       }
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Actions obj = new Actions();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented code to find the second word yet? What do you mean by 'it does not work'?

Comment: You only ever check against the first word ( `if (userInput.equals(words[0])) {` ), so of course it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you have to check **every** word of the user input.

Try this:

```
String[] inputs = userInput.split(" ");
String[] words = sentence.split(" ");

boolean result = true;

for(int i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) {
    result &= inputs[i].equals(words[i]);          // checking every word
}

if (result) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "They match!");
    input.setText("");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "They don't match!");
    input.setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only ever check against the first word, `if (userInput.equals(words[0])) {`, so of course it doesn't work.

(As a side note, your for loop does nothing.)

If you want the user to input one word at a time, you need to keep track of which word is the next word to check against. So, you can add a variable that gets incremented each time a user succeeds in entering the next word, and use that variable as the index in `words` (instead of `0`) in the `if` statement I mentioned above.